# Android, Files are not displayed when arrives to my created external folder

Tags: android, file, media

I have an issue with my app, files when arrive , pictures or other kind of files are stored in my custom file that is in the external storage, it saves them very well, for example i wanna watch a pictured that someone sent me, so when i go to gallery it doesn't show up anything like if there were no pictures, but when i see the file manager it is there.

It is displayed after a reboot. why is it happening? can someone give me any hint or an answer please i would appreciate it. i would like to know if there is a way to refresh it to see the files that arrived to my folder.

I created the file with this code:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

UPDATED:

```
private void refreshExternalStorage(final String filename){
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,  new String[]{String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()), filename},
                new String[]{"*/*", "*/*"},
                new MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
                    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                        Log.e("escanned", filename);
                    }

                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.e("escanne3232d", path);
                    }
                });
    }
```

WORKED FINE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Refresh External storage** Programatically:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" +  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

**Other way:**

```
private void refreshExternalStorage(){
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
            YourActivity.this,
            new String[]{"Your_First_File_Path", "Your_Second_File_Path"},
            new String[]{"*/*", "*/*"},
            new MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
            public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                    }

            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    }
                });
    }
```

Hope it will help you !

Comment: @kobbycoder, Can you please test your application in other device as well ?

Comment: lol sorry, i was putting it in the wrong function, it worked fine, thank you so muchhhh <333333 if i receive sound files, will it work for it too? and documents also?

Comment: @kobbycoder, yes its same for all files and glad to help you. :)

Comment: why is it always giving me a notification that it's scanning media files? D: cant i avoid that? is there a way to do it in the background without a toast and a notification?

Comment: @kobbycoder, it will give you notification for media scanner.

Comment: is there no other way to do it? or for example to automatically refresh my folder that i created in my external storage without giving me a notification?

Comment: @kobbycoder, I have added other code as well, let me know for the same.

Comment: @ Hiren Patel it doesn't work on emulator right?, it works perfectly on my devices but not on emulator, is it normal? i have tested on different SKDs and APIs for the emulator and different device versions. but doesn't seems to refresh on emulator.